# is it safe to modify variables in the via closure from the inner frame of a lambda that was create from a function that no longer function exists

Tags: c++, c++11

This works on g++ 4.7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>                                                                           

std::function<int()> make_counter() {
    return []()->std::function<int()> {
        int c=0;
        return [=]() mutable ->int {
            return  c++ ;
        };  
    }();
}   


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto count1= make_counter();
    auto count2= make_counter();

    std::cout << "count1=" << count1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count1=" << count1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count2=" << count2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count1=" << count1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count2=" << count2() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It seems like I should be able to do this because c no longer exists after make_function returns, but it is does

```
count1=0
count1=1
count1=2
count2=0
count1=3
count2=1
```

I'm guessing that the [=] makes it so the value of c stored and mutable is allows for the stored value to modified though I just want to make sure.

Valgrind doesn't complain about this at all. Every time I call make_counter, valgrind reports an additional allocation and free, so I assume the lambda meta programming code is inserting the allocation code for  the memory for variable . I'm wonder if this is Cxx11 compliant or if it's just g++ specific.

assuming the answer is correct, I could simplify make_counter to

```
std::function<int()> make_counter() {                                                             
      int c=0 ;
      return [=]() mutable ->int {
          return  c++ ;
      };  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.

By specifying `[=]` you made a *copy* of the local variable, and that copy is stashed, somewhere, in the lambda. The expression `c++` uses that local copy, which will live as long as the lambda does.

Note that the `mutable` would not have been necessary had `c` being referencing an external variable; its presence is made necessary by the fact that `c` is captured by copy and thus lives within the lambda "body".